# found the error "only one instance of the Robot class should be created"

Tags: python, webots

***Intoduction***
I am working on a Webots project in which four E-puck robots are used that push box to target locations with the Python class for each robot"Class Environment, class robot followed by main control loop"

**Code Snippet:**

````
    _robot_instance = None
    _supervisor_instance = None
    def __init__(self, use_supervisor=False):
        self.use_supervisor = use_supervisor
        self.TIME_STEP = 32
        self.receiver = None
        self.webots_supervisor = None
        if use_supervisor:
            if Environment._supervisor_instance is None:
                Environment._supervisor_instance = Supervisor()
            self.webots_supervisor = Environment._supervisor_instance
            self.robot = self.webots_supervisor.getFromDef("agent1")
        else:
            if Environment._robot_instance is None:
                Environment._robot_instance = Robot()
            self.robot = Environment._robot_instance
   def reset(self):
        print(f"Supervisor: {self.webots_supervisor}")
        # Release existing Robot/Supervisor instance if it exists
        if self.use_supervisor:
            if Environment._supervisor_instance is not None:
                self.webots_supervisor = None
                self.robot = None
                del Environment._supervisor_instance
        else:
            if Environment._robot_instance is not None:
                self.robot = None
        # Create a new Robot/Supervisor instance
        if self.use_supervisor:
            Environment._supervisor_instance = Supervisor()
            self.webots_supervisor = Environment._supervisor_instance
            self.robot = self.webots_supervisor.getFromDef("agent1")
        else:
            if Environment._robot_instance is None:
                Environment._robot_instance = Robot()
            self.robot = Environment._robot_instance
        try:
            # Ensure that Supervisor instance is used when appropriate
            root = (
                self.webots_supervisor.getRoot()
                if self.use_supervisor
                else self. robot.getRoot()
            )
            self.print_node_names(root)
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(f"Error getting nodes: {e}")```
**Issue:**
when I run it I end up getting an error like this:
Only one instance of the Robot class should be created
WARNING: 'Supervisor' controller exited with status: -1.
````

Comment: The error suggests that you are creating more than one object of Robot class and consuming it while only one is allowed, can you include the code snippet, for furthermore clearance.

Comment: in the reset function, when you release the robot object `self.robot = none` you also need to release the existing one before creating new try adding `del Environment._robot_instance` below it and that should do the job.

Comment: it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Sumanjha,got the same error, along with this print error message "Error getting nodes: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getFromDef'
Error getting nodes: 'Robot' object has no attribute 'getRoot'
Supervisor: None"that may help to understand more.